# prevent multiple installation of my android app

Tags: android

I want to control installation of my app on each device by sending its ANDROID_ID to a server and control it there. But according to this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) in android developers blog this isn't a suitable approach to do that.It says:

> the requirement is to identify a particular installation, not a physical device. Fortunately, doing so is straightforward.

I want to know how this way is possible for my needs?

**Edits:**
let me explain this more clear. I want to get user a registration code and let the user to install my app on 3 different devices by using this code and control this by a server.

Comment: The article posits that you should track the *installation* (via a unique ID you generate on first run) or the *user* (e.g., via `AccountManager` API), not the *device*. However, if you really must track the device, `ANDROID_ID` is a safe bet on modern devices.

Comment: @user113215: Only if by "safe bet" you ignore rooted device users, ROM mods, people simply revising the app to remove this check, etc. Indeed, that may meet the OP's needs, and it's certainly as good an option as any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, on rooted devices there is not much you can do. When one tempers with the ROM he can make two different devices identical: every API call aiming at finding a difference can be altered to return the same value. So if you want a solution that is absolutely safe, you're screwed.
With normal users seeing the problems in the Android API, I would suggest a hash of every device identifier you can find: IMEI, IMSI, ANDROID_ID, MAC address, Device type, manufacturer... This way you will surely grant 3 installations to normal users.

It's always better to have some free-riders than to have angry customers who cannot install the app on 3 devices because of some Android API bug that gave them the same device ID for their devices.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try to do my strategy in a different way